# Afterglow Prismatic Controller Xbox One Reset?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

So I got an Xbox One afterglow prismatic controller and I accidentally mapped the control sticks and can't remap them. Anyone know how to reset the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Power the XBOX one console on.
2. Plug the smaller end of the controllers USB-B micro cable into the top of the controller.
3. Hold down on the directional pad (D-Pad) and plug the larger side of the USB cable into the XBOX one console while still holding down.
4. The controllers red LED lights will illuminate and the controller will begin to vibrate. You may then release the down input on the directional pad (D-Pad)
5. Press A on the controller.
6. The controller will then stop vibrating and the LED lights will power off.
7. Fully rotate both joysticks in a complete clockwise motion and pull each trigger fully (LT and RT)
8. Press down on the directional pad (D-Pad)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It appeared to have performed a factory reset on my controller. However, when I try to pull the triggers, they do not respond.

Comment: Another late response, maybe you can help me with this problem too. Whenever i flick the left stick to the left, it also is mapped to pushing the stick. Any ideas?

Comment: @yoyoguy15 You have this answer marked as "accepted", which indicates that it solved your problem. Was your problem solved, or no?

Answer (score 0):

If any of that doesn't work you can also download the afterglow app on your Xbox One and reset your mapping manually

Answer (score -1):

I had the same thing happen when I reset the controller. Just reset controller and rotate the joysticks separately and the triggers as well if that makes sense.