# Xbox One Afterglow remote

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

So my XBOX ONE Afterglow controller will still power on, but it won't respond to controls.  It won't turn on my system from the remote by holding down the "X".  The Afterglow app on my system says the remote isn't connected, when it firmly is.  I've tried powering off/on, & leaving it disconnected.  The cable appears not to have any short, as it's able to charge my daughters' Leap Pad.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the remote as outlined in this answer on a different question:

[Afterglow Prismatic Controller Xbox One Reset?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/251999/afterglow-prismatic-controller-xbox-one-reset)

> Power the XBOX one console on.
>
> Plug the smaller end of the controllers USB-B micro cable into the top
>   of the controller.
>
> Hold down on the directional pad (D-Pad) and plug the larger side of
>   the USB cable into the XBOX one console while still holding down.
>
> The controllers red LED lights will illuminate and the controller will
>   begin to vibrate. You may then release the down input on the
>   directional pad (D-Pad)
>
> Press A on the controller.
>
> The controller will then stop vibrating and the LED lights will power
>   off.
>
> Fully rotate both joysticks in a complete clockwise motion and pull
>   each trigger fully (LT and RT)
>
> Press down on the directional pad (D-Pad)

Comment: Ok, I tried that & the issue still persist.  I've noticed that when it's plugged in, & I turn on my Xbox from the console, the remote doesn't respond as well.

Comment: Then your remote is probably broken. I suggest bringing it back to the store and exchanging it.