# What should I do if my Xbox One Afterglow controller has a constant single red glow?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

My Xbox one controller always has a single red glow.  It won't let me use the keyboard for some reason, it just freezes my game.  Do I need to reset it?

[image: my controller]

Comment: Is the controller vibrating as well? That looks more like the red LED for a factory reset: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/252773/51332